# Why would my map only display 50%

Tags: css, mapbox

I have created a map in mapbox and placed it on my site. For some reason only 50% of the map displays on my site.

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571611/positioning-a-mapbox-leaflet-map-inside-a-container-div), I added #map-container, but I still get the same result.

**Mapbox code:**

```
<!--mapbox-->
  <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<!--end mapbox-->
```

**CSS:**

```
#map-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#map {
  height: 600px;
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="map-container">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>

<script>
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2VhbmRyYWFkbG96ZSIsImEiOiJjajA3cW1pOTcwMDA5Mndvd2hicHlmNWc1In0.7bt7sPXDoymYJyVDvVmqZw';

  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/yourstyle/cj5j5jl0c0bvb2rnamu85jjfp',
    center: [29.184, -28.227],
    pitch: 60, // pitch in degrees
    bearing: -60, // bearing in degrees
    zoom: 10
  });
</script>
```

Here is the screenshot of my problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html,
body,
#map {
 width:100%;
height:100%, 
position:absolute;
margin:0;
z-index:1;
}
```

I think it is necessary to specify the map height explicitely where in your case it was 600px. Try using the above code.
Note : as z index is 1 any z below 1 will be hidden

Answer (score -2):

```
     <style>         
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
```

Comment: Maybe it would help other is if you could just give a short explanation of what you edit to the code does?

Comment: Although I still have the same issue.

Comment: remove it  #map { height:600px; }

Comment: nope, same results. I have added a screenshot to the question

Comment: good now change some css in  html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      } tag change margin and padding

Comment: is it completed

Comment: I am just trying to figure out how to get it centered again mate.